# Comma Between a Conjunction and an Adverb

Tags: commas, conjunctions

I would like to ask if a comma is needed before the adverb that succeeds the conjunction "and"?

> After finishing our stuff at the police station, we walked out, and surprisingly, we found our parents standing beside their cars on the parking lot.

Comment: As Greybeard says, the commas should surround "surprisingly", an adverb functioning as an evaluative adjunct. The proposition "We walked out, and we found our parents standing beside their cars on the parking lot" is presented as a fact, and the speaker adds an evaluation which amounts to saying “It was surprising that this was true".

Comment: This is a matter of style. Technically, you would need three commas: *After finishing, we walked out, and, surprisingly, we found our parents...* Because that is awkward, style guides will suggest either *After finishing, we walked out and, surprisingly, we found our parents...* or *After finishing, we walked out, and surprisingly, we found our parents...*

Answer (score 3):

The comma is *after* **and** because that comma, and the comma after "surprisingly", offsets the parenthetical adverb:

After finishing our stuff at the police station, we walked out and, surprisingly, we found our parents standing beside their cars